# Inherit/extend equivalent in handlebars

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js

I am working on a static template and decided to use handlebars and gulp to generate the html part.

I have read several examples and I understand the concept of importing a partial like:

*partial.hbs*

```
<h1>Contents of the partial</h1>
```

*index.hbs*

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {{> partial }}
    </body>
</html>
```

which would yield:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Contents of the partial</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I can't seem to find is extending a base file instead of importing into it. What I mean is this:

*base.hbs*

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {{ contents }}
    </body>
</html>
```

*index.hbs*

```
{{extend base}}
{{ contents }}
    <h1>Contents of the partial</h1>
{{ end contents }}
```

What is the proper way to do this in handlebars?